# cannot oinvoke tomcat manager exception in eclipse maven

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

when i work with maven spring project in eclipse , have some issues with maven plugin inside eclipse.
I have installed maven outside eclipse by download directly from the site. Then i download eclipse Luna release which has inbuild M2E . i  import my project as maven project then maven tomcat:redeploy RUN from eclipse but shows below error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:redeploy (default-cli) on project rolltickets: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Frolltickets&war=&update=true -> [Help 1]
```

But when i run this from out side eclipse as mvn tomcat:redeploy it works 
I have done with the tomcat users adding and everything else, obviously thats why its working outside eclipse.

Why it doesnt work from eclipse.
Please help.

Comment: It says Http code 401 : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error

Comment: Try to switch eclipse to external maven installation

Comment: How can i switch? Thnks

Comment: window/preferences/maven/Installations - Add... (select your maven installation), and them make it the default (checkbox)

Comment: Thanks Ralph and  Konstantin V. Salikhov it works.